# Python on Win10 much slower then Python on macOS

Tags: python

Im writing a program that scans folders and files to write those into a big flat file of a specific format. Basically I'm done with the program, but I can see **huge** performance diffs on macOS vs Win10.

A folder/subfolder with approx 12.000 files takes around 20secs on macOS, an OK result.
On Win 10 (same hardware) it takes **25min** !!!

Thats a 1000 times slower.

On macOS I'm on Python 2.7.16 on Win10 I'm using 3.8.3. But other then that no differences.
Is python really that much slower on Windows ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import struct
import time
import shutil

if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

class LIFHeader:
    '''
    LIF Header (18 bytes total):
    4 bytes Char[4] Header (ASCI = 'LIFF')
    4 bytes Int32   Spacing (Always equals 0)
    4 bytes Int32   Total file size (Int32 big endian)
    2 bytes Int16   Value "1" (Int16 big endian)
    4 bytes Int32   Spacing (Always equals 0)
    '''
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.magic = b'LIFF'            #Magic Word (ASCI = 'LIFF')
        self.spacing1 = struct.pack('>I', 0)    #Spacing (Always equals 0)
        self.size = struct.pack('>I',3405691582)#0xCAFEBABE - Just to test and also to verify that header size is set correct later
        self.spacing2 = struct.pack('>H', 1)    #Value "1" (Int16 big endian)
        self.spacing3 = struct.pack('>I', 0)    #Spacing (Always equals 0)

    def setSize(self, size):
        self.size = struct.pack('>I', size)

    def getSize(self):
        return struct.unpack('>I', self.size)[0]
    
    def string(self):
        out = b''.join([self.magic, self.spacing1, self.size, self.spacing2 + self.spacing3])
        return out

class LIFBlock: 
    '''
    LIF Block (20 bytes + data):
    2 bytes Int16   Block start/header (always 1)
    2 bytes Int16   Block type (1 to 5)
    4 bytes     Spacing1 (Always equals 0)
    4 bytes Int32   Block size in bytes (includes header and data)
    4 bytes     Spacing2 (Equals 1 for block types 2,4 and 5)
    4 bytes     Spacing3 (Always equals 0)
    X bytes     The block content/data.
    
    The block type 1 is the "root block" and its size includes the remainder of the LIF file.
    The block type 2 contains the files content/data. The block content seems hard-coded and it is always 1 (Int16) and 0 (Int32).
    The block type 3 represents a folder. The block content is a hierarchy of type 3 and 4 blocks.
    The block type 4 represents a file. The block data is the file content/data.
    The block type 5 contains the files and folders names and some more information. 
    The block content is a hierarchy of LIF entries.
    Note: The block header is 20 bytes total. The data size is equal to the specified size - 20 bytes.
    '''
    
    def __init__(self, blocktype, data):
        self.blockheader = struct.pack('>H', 1)     #Block start/header (always 1)
        self.blocktype = struct.pack('>H', blocktype)   #Block type (1 to 5)
        self.spacing1 = struct.pack('>I', 0)        #Spacing (Always equals 0)
                                #Block size in bytes (includes header and data) <- calculated later
        if blocktype == 1 or blocktype == 3:
            self.spacing2 = struct.pack('>I', 0)
        else:
            self.spacing2 = struct.pack('>I', 1)    #Spacing (Equals 1 for block types 2,4 and 5)
        self.spacing3 = struct.pack('>I', 0)        #Spacing (Always equals 0)
        if blocktype == 2:
            self.data = b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00' #The block content seems hard-coded for blocktype 2 and is always 1 (Int16) and 0 (Int32)
        else:
            self.data = data
        
        self.size = struct.pack('>I',len(self.data)+20) #Block size in bytes (includes header and data)

    def setSize(self, size):
        self.size = struct.pack('>I', size)

    def getSize(self):
        return struct.unpack('>I', self.size)[0]

    def string(self):
        out = b''.join([self.blockheader, self.blocktype, self.spacing1, self.size, self.spacing2, self.spacing3, self.data])
        return out
        
class LIFDirEntry:
    '''
    SIZE    TYPE    DESCRIPTION
    2 bytes Int16   Entry type (equals 1)
    4 bytes Int32   Unknown value (equals 0 or 7) The value 0 seems to be used for the root folder.
    N bytes Char[]  Folder name. (Unicode null-terminated text)
    4 bytes Spacing (Always equals 0)
    4 bytes Int32?  Block size (Always equals 20 so it equals the block header size)
    4 bytes Int32   The number of sub-entries (files and folders)
    '''

    def __init__(self, rootind, name, entries):
        self.entrytype = struct.pack('>H', 1)       #Entry type (equals 1)
        self.rootind = struct.pack('>I', rootind)   #Unknown value (equals 0 or 7) The value 0 seems to be used for the root folder.
        self.name = b'\x00' + name.encode('utf-16')[2:] + b'\x00'
        self.spacing1 = struct.pack('>I', 0)        #Spacing (Always equals 0)
        self.size = struct.pack('>I', 20)       #Block size (Always equals 20 so it equals the block header size)
        self.entries = struct.pack('>I',entries)    #The number of sub-entries (files and folders)

    def string(self):
        out = b''.join([self.entrytype, self.rootind, self.name, self.spacing1, self.size, self.entries])
        return out


class LIFFileEntry:
    '''
    SIZE    TYPE    DESCRIPTION
    2 bytes Int16   Entry type (equals 2)
    4 bytes Int32   Spacing/unknown value (0 or 7)
    N bytes Char[]  File name. (Unicode null-terminated text)
    4 bytes Spacing (Always equals 0)
    4 bytes Int32   File size (it is actually the block size because it includes the block header size (20))
    8 bytes Long    Created, modified or accessed date
    8 bytes Long    Created, modified or accessed date
    8 bytes Long    Created, modified or accessed date
    '''

    def __init__(self, name, size):
        self.entrytype = struct.pack('>H', 2)       #Entry type (equals 2)
        self.unknwown = struct.pack('>I', 7)        #Spacing/unknown value (0 or 7).
        self.name = b'\x00' + name.encode('utf-16')[2:] + b'\x00'
        self.spacing1 = struct.pack('>I', 0)        #Spacing (Always equals 0)
        self.size = struct.pack('>I', size)     #File size (it is actually the block size because it includes the block header size (20))
        self.created = struct.pack('>Q', 18369614221190020847)  #Created, modified or accessed date
        self.modified = struct.pack('>Q', 18369614221190020847) #Created, modified or accessed date. Set to 0xFEEDFACECAFEBEEF for testing
        self.accessed = b'\x01\xce\xec\xee\x85\x3b\x50\xdb'     #Created, modified or accessed date

    def string(self):
        out = b''.join([self.entrytype, self.unknwown, self.name, self.spacing1, self.size, self.created, self.modified, self.accessed])
        return out


def createLif(walk_dir):
    outfile = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(walk_dir))
    number_of_files = 0
    print('LIF Creator 1.1')
    print('Choosen directory: {0}'.format(os.path.normpath(walk_dir)))
    
    #Create the first non-existant file to write to.
    if os.path.exists(outfile + '.lif'):
        i = 1
        while(os.path.exists(outfile + "_" + str(i) + '.lif')):
            i += 1
        outfile = outfile + "_" + str(i)
    
    start_time = time.time()
    
    fi_content_str = b''
    fo_dict = {}
    fh_dict = {}
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(walk_dir, topdown=False):
        #ignore hidden files and folders (starting with a dot .)
        files = [f for f in files if not f[0] == '.']
        subdirs[:] = [d for d in subdirs if not d[0] == '.']
        
        files_content_str = b''
        files_fh_str = b''
        for filename in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            
            sys.stdout.write('\tPROCESSING: {0}          \r'.format(filename))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            #print('Processing: {0}'.format(file_path))
            
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                current_data = f.read()
                currenFileBlock = LIFBlock(blocktype=4, data=current_data) #Content of single file: Block Type 4
                currenFileEntry = LIFFileEntry(name=filename, size=currenFileBlock.getSize())
                fi_content_str = currenFileBlock.string()
                fh_content_str = currenFileEntry.string()
                
            files_content_str = files_content_str + fi_content_str #Content of all files in current folder
            files_fh_str = files_fh_str + fh_content_str
        
        subfolders_content_str = b''
        subfolders_fh_str = b''
        for subdir in subdirs:
            subfolders_content_str = subfolders_content_str + fo_dict[os.path.join(root, subdir)]
            subfolders_fh_str = subfolders_fh_str + fh_dict[os.path.join(root, subdir)]
            fo_dict.pop(os.path.join(root, subdir), None) #Drop item from fo dict, its no longer needed
            fh_dict.pop(os.path.join(root, subdir), None) #Drop item from fh dict, its no longer needed
            
        currenBlock = LIFBlock(blocktype=3, data=files_content_str + subfolders_content_str) #Block Type 3
        number_entries = len(files) + len(subdirs)
        currenDirEntry = LIFDirEntry(rootind=7, name=os.path.basename(root) , entries=number_entries)
        fo_dict[root] = currenBlock.string()
        fh_dict[root] = currenDirEntry.string() + files_fh_str + subfolders_fh_str
        
        number_of_files = number_of_files + len(files)
    
    '''Root directory block (Block Type 3)'''
    #rootDirBlock = LIFBlock(blocktype=3, data=fo_dict[root])
    rootDirBlock= fo_dict[root]
    
    '''File Content Block (Block Type 2)'''
    fileContentBlock = LIFBlock(blocktype=2, data='')
    
    '''File hierarchy (Block Type 5)'''
    fhBlock = LIFBlock(blocktype=5, data=fh_dict[root])
    
    '''Root Block (Block Type 1)'''
    rootBlock = LIFBlock(blocktype=1, data=fileContentBlock.string() + rootDirBlock + fhBlock.string())
    
    '''Header'''
    headerBlock = LIFHeader()
    headerBlock.setSize(len(rootBlock.string()) + 18)
    
    print('\n\tCOMPLETED: {0} files processed. Will now write {1}.lif.'.format(str(number_of_files), outfile))
    lif_file = open((outfile + '.lif'), "wb")
    lif_file.write(headerBlock.string())
    lif_file.write(rootBlock.string())
    lif_file.close()
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

if(len(sys.argv) > 1):
    for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
        createLif(sys.argv[i])
else:
    print("LIF Creator 1.1\n\nThis program will create LIF archives from an adjacent folder.\n\nCOPYRIGHT:\n\t(C) 2020 sttng\n\nLICENSE:\n\tGNU GPLv3\n\tYou accept full responsibility for how you use this program.\n\nUSEAGE:\n\t" + runCommand + " <FILE_PATHS>")
```

Comment: Obvious question : does both computers have the same hardware configuration ? Or do you run his scirppt on the same computer with two OS installed ?

Comment: Its the same computer on dual boot.

Comment: There is no doubt here that it is more an allocated resources issue than an OS problem.  Dual bot on mac can cause performances issues especially if it is not configured properly. Can you check the resources allocated to your VM windows instance ?

Comment: This is not a VM, this is dual boot via bootcamp  - so basically 2 partitions and VM performance bottle necks are not existing in that case.